# Tool tip with Font-Awesome and table

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I am trying to add a tool-tip to an icon inside the table-cell using title attribute. The tooltip seems to work fine outside the table for icons but inside the table it doesnt work properly.
Following is the js-fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/amahajan/7vyhzgod/1/

```
<td><div>D</div>
<div class="lock-posn"><i class="fas fa-eye fa-sm"></i></div>
<div class="mis-match"><a href="#" title ="Warning"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-sm"></i></a></div>
</td>
```

Please let me know how do I handle this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change css of `.lock-posn` and `.mis-match`, due to position:absolute ,it's not showing `title tooltip`

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    table-layout: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
}

thead th{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 75px;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-bottom-color: grey;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

 tbody td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#opt-staff-table th.opt-staff-sticky-col {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    left: 0;
    top: 75px;
    z-index: 4;
}

.lock-posn {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.mis-match {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" />

<a href="#" title="Show the previous 4 weeks"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Day1</th>
<th>Day2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div>D</div>
<div class="mis-match"><a href="#" title ="Warning"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-sm"></i></a></div>
<div class="lock-posn"><i class="fas fa-eye fa-sm"></i></div>
</td>
<td><div>E</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div>N</div></td>
<td><div>A</div></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine however, I am not able to position the icon to the corners of the cell without using position absolute. Is there any round about for that? Also why does position:absolute prevents the title from showing up

Comment: i tried lot but i didn't get any other method for it and position absolute element respective to its relative element and respective element is TD , so its not visible for absolute position

Answer (score 0):

try putting this

```
<td><div>D</div>
<div class="lock-posn"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-sm"></i></div>
<div class="mis-match"><a href="#" title ="Warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-sm"></i></a></div>
</td>
```

I always used this with fa.